# Distribution after adding noise to a Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I have a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$. Now, I add a noise $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_N^2)$ to $X$ to get $Y$ ($Y = X + N$). Thus, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_N^2)$. Are $Y$ and $X$ bivariate normal now? If so, what would be the density function $f_{Y|X}$?

Comment: If $N$ is independent of $X$ then $(X,Y)=(X,X+N)$ has a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Right. So I can assume some value $\rho$ as correlation coefficient and use the bivaraiate normal formula to represent $f_{y|x}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$X+N\: | \: X=x \sim x+N \: | \: X=x.$$
If we also know that $X$ and $N$ are independent, then we can infer that
$$x+N \: | \: X=x \sim x+N \sim \mathcal{N}(x, \sigma_N^2),$$
which means that $Y|X \sim \mathcal{N}(X,\sigma_N^2)$.

For the part about bivariate normal distribution, you may use that linear transformations of a bivariate normal vector is again bivariate normal. So if $(X,N)$ is bivariate normal (which it is if we assume independence), then $(X,X+N)$ is also bivariate normal.

Comment: Does it mean that the mean of $Y|X$ is $\mu_X$ and variance is $\sigma_N^2$?

Comment: The mean of $Y|X$ is $X$ (not $\mu_X$) and variance is $\sigma_N^2$. The mean of $Y$ is however
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \:|\: X]] = \mathbb{E}[X]=\mu_X$$

Comment: So, if I use $X = x_1$, then the mean of $Y|X$ would be $x_1$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, although when a particular value of $X$ is considered, you should write $Y|X=x_1$, as in 

"The mean of $Y|X=x_1$ is $x_1$".

Comment: Got it. Thanks!